# how to make substring in Python but for my example?

Tags: python, eclipse

I have a string like this:

```
<node> user = "bob" password ="123" </node> <node> user = "john" password ="123" </node> <node> user = "will" password ="1234" </node> <node> user = "andrew" password ="12345" </node> <node> user = "mike" password ="123456" </node>
```

How can I extract only users? I want to get a list having bob, john, will, andrew, mike and all others that have this format: `user = "XXXX"`

I checked some substrings methods, but none solved my problem. You can set a start and end index with slicing method, but I don't want to use integers, I want to search by string.

Comment: *"Could you please any codes to solve my problem?"* - that is **not** how Stack Overflow works. *Write some yourself*, and learn [ask]. *"how to make ... but for my example"* is the **whole point of learning things**, if you can't adopt general solutions to your specific needs then you're stuffed (and SO is pointless).

Comment: Your answer is pointless. I only used "to solve my problem" for not getting answers that I already tried (I always Google first). My problem is much bigger than this question. but I made it very objective and simple so that people can spend less time reading, I spend less time waiting, then I get a code that works and come up with a solution for my problem using the code provided. And this is the point of learning. Fast and simple.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. I appreciate the effort to pare this down to the core problem, but SO is **not** here so you *"spend less time waiting, then... get a code that works"*. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a simple regular expression:

```
>>> s = '<node> user = "bob" password ="123" </node> <node> user = "john" password ="123" </node> <node> user = "will" password ="1234" </node> <node> user = "andrew" password ="12345" </node> <node> user = "mike" password ="123456" </node>'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'user = "(\w+)"', s)
['bob', 'john', 'will', 'andrew', 'mike']
```

If you need to support names that have spaces in them, the regular expression changes slightly.  Change the capturing group from `\w+` (all alpha-numeric characters) to `[^"]+` (everything that isn't a double quote):

```
>>> s = '<node> user = "bob jones" password ="123" </node> <node> user = "john" password ="123" </node> <node> user = "will" password ="1234" </node> <node> user = "andrew" password ="12345" </node> <node> user = "mike" password ="123456" </node>'
>>> re.findall(r'user = "([^"]+)"', s)
['bob jones', 'john', 'will', 'andrew', 'mike']
```

I'm sure that there are better methods (maybe parsing out `node` tags first with an `xml` parser and *then* parsing the "user = ..." from the node.) but this should at least point you in the right direction or help shape your thinking about the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot test it but It was very helpful. I'll work on this.

Comment: That worked, but I still figuring how to extract names with spaces in it: Eg: Bob Johnson.. it gets only Bob

Comment: @AndréRamos -- I think that `r'user = "([^"]+)'` would work for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way to learn about Python strings and lists.  Given that you initially have a string, strings have a split method that allows you to break a string based on the value passed to split

```
my_list = string.split('=')
```

So this splits your string on the = sign the sections split are collected in a list

```
my_list = ['<node> user ', ' "bob" password ', '"123" </node> <node> user ', ' "john" password ', '"123" </node> <node> user ', ' "will" password ', '"1234" </node> <node> user ', ' "andrew" password ', '"12345" </node> <node> user ', ' "mike" password ', '"123456" </node>']
```

If you look carefully, the names are included in the list items that also have the word password so we will use that regularity to get to the next step

```
names = []  # this will hold the names after we find them
for item in my_list:
    if 'password' not in item:
        continue # if password is not in the item then we don't want to do anything so get the next item
    name = item.strip().split(' ')[0]  # get rid of the leading blank space (and trailing) then split on the blank space keep the first item in the resulting list
    name = name.replace('"','') # I assume you want to get rid of the double quotes as they are not part of the name
    names.append(name)
```

Now names is a list of names

```
['bob', 'john', 'will', 'andrew', 'mike']
```